# IOS how to listen on Power button event

Tags: ios, events, button

i'm trying to make a small tool in IOS which will require password while trying to shutdown(press Power button) the machine.

but I can't find any reference to listen on PowerButton to check whether the machine is going to shutdown..

Can someone advise?

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: I don't think you can override system level actions like holding the power button, pressing the home button, overriding the mute sound switch within your own app. iOS system doesn't exactly behave like an normal computer OS, it's much more limited.

Comment: agree.  But what if after jailbraeak? is there any solution/ framwork to do that?